# Find any 2 dates in core data which are the same?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, filter

Due to difficult circumstances, it's possible my user might end up with duplicate data. Included in each entity of a certain type is a date. Would I be able to find out if there are any duplicates in core data, without iterating through every piece of data to look for it's duplicate?

Comment: The dates must be exactly the same to the millisecond.  Will this be true?

Comment: @borrrden yes, as it will be duplicate data

Comment: I think it might help to know more about the "difficult circumstances".  Usually, you can check for the record and update it if it exists, and create it if it doesn't.  Queuing will greatly help you achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

well, I'm not sure if there is a core data routine to do this. But you could get all the records ordered by date, then in a single pass you can find duplicates by comparing the nth item in the array to n+1 item in the array. If their dates match, then they are duplicates.

As an added optimisation, record the previous date that you had checked your data against. If the user cannot add records in the past, then you only need to check for dates past this recorded date.

Answer (score 0):

No.  There is no way to know if you have duplicates without comparing the data.